# Oracle Sql Joining from 3 tables

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

This is my solution for querying the columns needed:

```
"SELECT " +
            "OL.ORDER_NO, OL.ITEM, OL.LOCATION, OL.LOC_TYPE, OL.QTY_ORDERED, OL.UNIT_COST, OL.UNIT_RETAIL, " +
            "OL.QTY_PRESCALED, OL.QTY_RECEIVED, OL.LAST_RECEIVED, OL.LAST_ROUNDED_QTY, OL.LAST_GRP_ROUNDED_QTY, " +
            "OL.QTY_CANCELLED, OL.CANCEL_CODE, OL.CANCEL_DATE, OL.CANCEL_ID, OL.ORIGINAL_REPL_QTY, OL.UNIT_COST_INIT, " +
            "OL.COST_SOURCE, OL.NON_SCALE_IND, OL.TSF_PO_LINK_NO, OL.ESTIMATED_INSTOCK_DATE, OS.REF_ITEM, " +
            "OS.ORIGIN_COUNTRY_ID, OS.EARLIEST_SHIP_DATE, OS.LATEST_SHIP_DATE, OS.SUPP_PACK_SIZE, " +
            "OS.PICKUP_LOC, OS.PICKUP_NO, WH.WH_NAME " +
            "FROM RMS.ORDLOC OL " +
            "left outer join RMS.WH WH on WH.WH = OL.LOCATION " +
            "join RMS.ORDSKU OS on OS.ORDER_NO = OL.ORDER_NO and OS.ITEM = OL.ITEM " +
            "WHERE OL.ORDER_NO IN(:ORDER_NO)";
```

This solution gives me what I need, I'm just curious about if it is the best solution in terms of query speed.

I'm not sure how to figure out the time complexity and if this is the best solution for the query. I have very limited knowledge on relational algebra. My understanding is to join smaller tables into the larger table which I am doing, and to avoid or's which I am doing. But is there a better query that I am not seeing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody can answer that without understanding your data, its cardinalities, your indexing options, and seeing ASH wait data at the plan step level. Tuning is just too complicated to get an easy answer from a forum like this.

Comment: Don't bother reordering the joins, the optimizer will choose the join order it finds the best anyway.

Comment: thanks Paul W, I understand that, I was just more so concerned with breaking any like "cardinal rules" that could cause issues down the road.